# Write a function taking arbitrary objects and methods with common return types

Tags: c#

I have several objects of different types with methods taking different parameters that all return the same type. These methods can fail. Is there a way to write a function that will take the object and its method, indicate if the method fails, and indicate the object on which failure occurred? I can't modify the Result object, and it holds no information about the object that called it.

I find this a little verbose:

```
Result resultA = A.something();
if(resultA.Failed) return new Status{Failed=A.GetType().ToString()};

Result resultB = B.somethingElse(3);
if(resultB.Failed) return new Status{Failed=B.GetType().ToString()};

Result result3 = C.someOtherThing("apple");
if(resultC.Failed) return new Status{Failed=C.GetType().ToString()};

// Do some processing of the results (will succeed if A,B,C succeeded)

return new Status {Failed=null, Success=true};
```

Is there a way to encapsulate all that into a function? It seems very repetitive. A, B, and C do not inherit from a useful base class, and their methods all take different parameters and have different names.

That being said, I do have access to the Status class, and even the return value of this function. The function need not return, it could throw an exception instead. If there's a failure, the function can break immediately.

Comment: This sounds like a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), can you give a bigger picture of what is going on? A shot in the dark, you are using WCF and this is for communicating back the error without faulting the connection?

Comment: I'm calling MVC web services. I make several calls from different clients, all of which return a Result with an http status code.

Comment: Your example requires a little clarification: if, say- all methods succeed, what should be the output? on the other hand, if one of the methods fail- do you want to continue execution of other methods or break immediately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Suggest a small variation to @Shawn Holzworth's answer that is a bit simpler.

First, since the only thing in common to your methods is their return type, this is the only thing that we can generalize here. We can construct a methods that will handle the execution as you requested like so:

```
 public static Status ExecuteRequests(params Func<Result>[] actions){
  foreach (Func<Result> action in actions) {
    Result r = action();
    if (!r.Success) {
      Status s = new Status() { Failed = action.Target.GetType().ToString() };
      return s;
    }
  }

  return new Status() { Success = true };
}
```

And the call site:

```
  ExecuteRequests(
    () => A.doSomething(), 
    () => B.doSomethingElse(42));
```

If you want to perfrom extra computation on the Results, you can extend the ExecuteRequests method to input a handler in the Form of Action.

This abstraction actually facilitates another thing that you did not ask about but I believe is worth mentioning: Parallel execution. When you encapsulate these operations like this, it is very easy to make use of the TPL, to send out the requests in parallel and aggregate them as the arrive, but this is a bit more involved.

Having mentioned the above, I wonder whether this is worth the effort. Indeed it abstracts the  execution sequence, but I am not sure that this significantly enhances readability (Unless you have a longer execution sequence than 3, and expect it to grow in the future).

Comment: I like this approach, but minor note: `action.Target.GetType()` is not the same as `A.GetType()`. `action.Target` is going to be either the object calling `ExecuteRequest(() => A.doSomething())` or null if you define the `Func<Result>` first like `Func<Result> f = ()=>a.Something();`.

Comment: @ShawnHolzworth, you are right of course. Eric can incorporate part of your approach (the Create method) but I am afraid the gain will not be worth the effort and the indirection.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is make a new subclass of `Status` that fills it the `Failed` property for you, you can just have the constructor take a `object` in as the type and call `GetType()` in there.

```
public class FailedStatus : Status
{
    public FailedStatus(object source)
    {
        this.Failed = source.GetType().ToString();
    }
}

Result resultA = A.something();
if(resultA.Failed) return new FailedStatus(A);

Result resultB = B.somethingElse(3);
if(resultB.Failed) return new FailedStatus(B);

Result result3 = C.someOtherThing("apple");
if(resultC.Failed) return new FailedStatus(C);
```

---

If `Result` derives from `Status` too the least verbose way is modify `something()`, `somethingElse(int)`, and `someOtherThing(string)` to set the string itself (but I doubt this is true sense it appears `Result.Failed` is a `bool` but `Status.Failed` is a `string`).

Answer (score 0):

One simple way you could do this:

```
//Note: the method signature could just be IEnumerable<Result> AggregateResults(params Func<Result>[]) 
//if you want to be able to aggregate the results of 0 calls
IEnumerable<Result> AggregateResults(Func<Result> func, params Func<Result>[] otherFuncs)
{
    yield return func();
    foreach(var otherFunc in otherFuncs)
        yield return otherFunc();
}

//Usage:
var results = AggregateResults(
    () => A.Something(),
    () => B.SomethingElse(3),
    () => C.SomethingOtherThing("apple"));
```

Unfortunately the requirement to stop on the first failing call and get the calling object makes it slightly harder:

```
class AggregateResult
{
    public object CallingObject;
    public Result Result;

    public static AggregateResult Create<T>(T t, Func<T,Result> func) 
    { 
        return new AggregateResult() { CallingObject = t, Result = func(t) }; 
    }
}
IEnumerable<AggregateResult> AggregateResults(Func<AggregateResult> func, params Func<AggregateResult>[] otherFuncs)
{
    yield return func();
    foreach (var otherFunc in otherFuncs)
        yield return otherFunc();
}
//Usage:
var results = AggregateResults(
            () => AggregateResult.Create(A, x=>x.Something()),
            () => AggregateResult.Create(B, x=>x.SomethingElse(3)),
            () => AggregateResult.Create(C, x=>x.SomethingOtherThing("apple")));
var failedResult = results.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Result.Failed);
if (failedResult != null) return new Status() { Failed = failedResult.CallingObject.GetType().ToString() };
```

That said, I agree with the comments that this sounds like an XY problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an extension method for Result that returns null in case of success, like this:

```
static class ResultExtension 
{
    public static Status GetStatus<T>(this Result res, T a) {
        return res.Failed? new Status{Failed=a.GetType().ToString()} : null;
    }
}
```

then you could chain operations with the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) `??` :

```
return A.something().GetStatus(A)             ??
       B.somethingElse(3).GetStatus(B)        ??
       C.someOtherThing("apple").GetStatus(C) ??
       new Status{Failed=null, Success=true};
```

note that [the ?? operator short-circuits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318912/does-c-sharp-operator-short-circuit), so you only evaluate somethingElse(3) or someOtherThing("apple") if none of the previous results is null (i.e. a failure), as you want and in the end, if and only if all calls succeeded you return a success Status.